# How to test the string to see if it contains two integers and if it does I need to use them in the acker function

Tags: java

This is what I have so far, if the string has two integers I need to pull them out and use them in the acker function that takes in two integers as parameters.

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    String nextLine = "";
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    AckerFunction x = new AckerFunction();

    System.out.println("Input two integers separated by a space character (enter q to quit):");
    try {
          nextLine = input.readLine(); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (nextLine.matches("[0-9]+") && nextLine.length() > 2) 
    {
        x.acker(m, n)
    }
```

Comment: OK, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: Where are you getting m and n from?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to get two integers from console. Use `nextInt()` method like in the code shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AckerFunction x = new AckerFunction();      
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input two integers separated by a space character");
        try {
            int m = input.nextInt();
            int n = input.nextInt();
            x.acker(m,n);
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input, please enter integers");
        }
        finally {
            input.close();
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `.Split()` method to split the string into an array to have direct access to any of the elements/numbers. Just an example:

```
String str = "123 456";
char c = ' ';
String[] s = str.Split(c);
double[] nums = new double[str.Length]
for(int i=0; i<s.Length; i++)
{
    double d;
    if(Double.TryParse(s[i], out d))
        nums[i] = d;
}
```

Just added some check so you won't have errors. If it's not a number, it'd stay `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the first two integers from a string and ignore all other characters. If you only want to get two numbers from the console `prudhvi` has the right answer.

```
String regex = "-?\\d+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nextLine);

int i = 0;
int[] val = new int[2];
while( matcher.find() && i++ < 2 )
  val[i-1] = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());

if( i == 2 )
  x.acker(val[0], val[1]);
```